# Passing data from window to viewmodel in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to wpf. I have a button in MainWindow. On button click I generate a SecondWindow. I want to pass `List<string>` from MainWindow to `SecondWindow`. I have a 'SecondViewModel' class as `Window.DataContext` of `SecondWindow`. The 'List' should be available for `SecondViewModel`. How do I do it?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Button x:Name="showSeondWindow"
         Content="Show second window"
         Click="showSeondWindow_Click"
        />
    </Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // should able to pass this list to second window
        List<string> dataToPass = new List<string>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataToPass.Add("apple");
            dataToPass.Add("banana");
            dataToPass.Add("orange");

        }

        private void showSeondWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // How to pass that list to second window???
            SecondWindow sw = new SecondWindow();
            sw.Show();
        }
    }
```

SecondWindow.xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:SecondViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

SecondViewModel.cs

```
public class SecondViewModel
    {
        public SecondViewModel()
        {
            // I want to use the List passed from main window to SecondWindow inside this
            // SecondViewModel Class
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: Why not to pass the list through the constructor?

Comment: @AdrianEfford then how do I use inside `SecondViewModel` class ?. I am totally new to wpf. Do I need to change something inside '<Window.DataContext>'

Comment: Let me create a detailed answer for you

Answer (score 2):

First remove the `DataContext` initialization from the XAML (for this scenario).
Then create the data context of the `SecondWindow` and initialize the `SecondWindow` instance with this data context.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // should able to pass this list to second window
    private List<string> DataToPass { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataToPass = new List<string> 
        {
          "apple",
          "banana",
          "orange"
        };
    }

    private void ShowSeondWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // How to pass that list to second window???

        var secondWindowViewModel = new SecondWindowViewModel(this.DataToPass);
        var secondWindow = new SecondWindow() { DataContext = secondWindowViewModel };
        secondWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**SecondWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class SecondWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> Data { get; }

    public SecondWindowViewModel(IEnumerable<string> data)
    {
        // I want to use the List passed from main window to SecondWindow inside this
        this.Data = data.ToList();

        // SecondViewModel Class
    }        
}
```

Then setup a binding from `SecondWindow` to the `SecondWindowViewModel` to display the data.

Note that for data binding your view model classes should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` from each property setter.